# Highslide gallery thumbnails issue

Tags: highslide

I am in the process of updating a website, which uses Highslide and a thumbnail strip on the bottom. The old website works ilke a charm but the new one fails. On my test website (newer layout) the thumbnail strip shows the last picture five times.

[Page on original website](http://www.onderwaterwereld.org/library/nl-zout/anthozoa/alcyonium%20digitatum)

[Page with the issue](http://test.oww.pritaeas.net/index.php?id=148)

The problem is on every detail page, so not just visible on this one page. The referenced libraries are identical on both servers. Hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, run your new page through a validator. You have an unclosed `<a href>`, and some unclosed `<div>` sections, and I think that may be throwing things for a loop.

[Validation of your page - click here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://test.oww.pritaeas.net/index.php?id=148&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Never even occurred to me to check validation. It was a missing `</a>`.

Comment: It's always the little stuff that traps us!